# Python asyncio program won't exit

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an asyncio/Python program with two asyncio tasks:

- one that crashes
- one that goes on for ever.

I want my entire program to exit after the first crash. I cannot get it to happen.

```
import asyncio
import time

def infinite_while():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


async def task_1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    assert False


async def task_2():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: infinite_while())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

tasks = asyncio.gather(task_2(), task_1())
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as e:
    print('ERROR', str(e))
    exit()
```

It prints ERROR but does not exit. When manually closed, the program prints the following stack trace:

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 39, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1054, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1070, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Have you tried cooperative exiting? Probably not what you want, but at least as an experiment, you could: change the loop in `infinite_while` to say `while not exit_requested`; change `task_1` to catch the assertion exception, set the flag, and reraise; and see if your call to exit() completes once each task has exited, one normally and one with the assertion exception.

Comment: Thanks, it works, will use it as a last resort but hoping there is a cleaner way to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an exception is risen in a task, it never propagates to the scope where the task was launched via eventloop, i.e. the `loop.run_until_complete(tasks)` call. Think of it, as if the exception is thrown only in the context of your task, and that is the top level scope where you have the chance to handle it, otherwise it will be risen in the *"background"*.

This said, you will never catch an `Exception` from the task with this:

```
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as e:
    print('ERROR', str(e))
    exit()
```

...and that is just how the event loop works. Imagine if you would have a service with several tasks, and one of them would fail, that would stop the whole service.

What you could do is [stop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.stop) the eventloop manually when you catch an exception in `task1`, e.g.

```
async def task_1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    try:
        assert False
    except Exception:
        # get the eventloop reference somehow
        eventloop.stop()
```

However, this is very dirty and kind of hacky, so I would rather suggest to go with the solution that [@D-Von suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351988/python-asyncio-program-wont-exit#comment66038061_39351988), which is much cleaner and safer.

Comment: I have a use case where I want exactly that. The event loop is started and stopped for a small part of the code where I need concurrency. If an exception occurs, I would prefer if the entire event loop stopped, and the program quit. In the event loop, I have several long-running, but not infinitely running processes, and I would like to cancel them all if one exception occurs. My perception is that asyncio is designed for a world where the eventloop is always running, but it's also a good library for different use cases - if exception handling were more transparent.

Comment: "Imagine if you would have a service with several tasks, and one of them would fail, that would stop the whole service." I think that full stop of the service is almost always the desired behavior, since behavior after one task has crashed is likely to be undefined and untested.